# could not install flutter in windows 10 ask permissions and got error while giving permission

Tags: android, flutter, dart

i got the following error while installing the flutter and giving the permission please help me how to solve this problem.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1110]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\sunil sapkota>flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1110], locale en-AU)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio
[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.57.1)
[√] Connected device (2 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

C:\Users\sunil sapkota>flutter doctor --android-licenses
Error: Could not find or load main class sapkota\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\\..
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sapkota\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\\//
```

**UPDATE**

i change the file path from  `Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest`
to  `Sdk\cmdline-tools\tools`
but this doesn't solve my problem but change the problem form ClassNotFoundException to classloader problem and got following error:

```
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1110], locale en-AU)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio
[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.57.1)
[√] Connected device (2 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

C:\Windows\System32>flutter doctor --android-licenses
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 5 more
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: run the command is  `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses. because android licence is not accepted on your system then run `flutter doctor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GO to Android SDK manager and install cmdline-tools inside of it using android studio.